# Android GetMap() returns me null

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem whit the GoogleMaps API on Android, I have a fragment who needs the mapsFragment inside, I can put the map inside the view with this code on the layout

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/map_container">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and with this code I can change for the mapsFragment

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
GoogleMaps googleMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true)).getMap();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.map_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

The problem comes when I try to put a mark or change anything on the mapFragment because I need to get the map with this code

```
GoogleMaps googleMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true)).getMap();
```

to do stuff like this `addMarker`, `moveCamera`, `animateCamera` but the SupportMapFragment.newInstance always returns me null. All this code is executing in onActivityCreated because if I try to handler this code on the onCreateView so I don't know what I can do in a fragment to get the map of GoogleMaps

Please help me!!

Comment: Carefully read the Google Maps API docs to determine the correct lifecycle.

Comment: You're creating two SupportMapFragment instances, and you're not calling `getMap()` on the SupportMapFragment instance that you're using for the FragmentTransaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is not ready by the time you make that call. Replace `getMap()` [with `getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29), then perform the rest of your map configuration in the `OnMapReadyCallback` and its `onMapReady()` method:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.nooyawk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends AbstractMapActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (readyToGo()) {
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      MapFragment mapFrag=
          (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    CameraUpdate center=
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
            -73.98180484771729));
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/NooYawk) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android))